# How to play sound in QML when qml is shown

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I need to play a sound in QML using SoundEffect, but all examples which I found play the sound based on some event (mouse clicked and so on ), but how to play the sound when the qml is shown?

This is example with mouse clicked:

```
SoundEffect {
     id: playSound
     source: "soundeffect.wav"
 }
 MouseArea {
     id: playArea
     anchors.fill: parent
     onPressed: { playSound.play() }
 }
```

Comment: "when the qml is shown" You mean once the main widget therein is shown, right?

Comment: @underscore_d yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a signal [`Component.completed`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal) that is emitted whenever an object that implements a component is instantiated:

```
MouseArea {
    id: playArea
    Component.onCompleted: playSound.play()
}
```

If it really is a graphical item and you need a sound played each time the item becomes visible, then handle the `visibleChanged` signal, for instance:

```
Rectangle {
    id: soundBox
    onVisibleChanged: if(visible) playSound.play()
}
```